# Does anybody know this typeface?

Tags: font-identification, font-recommendation, typefaces, sans-serif

I am trying to recreate the below poster. I have found substitute fonts for most of the text I just need help with the part that says "of the CHARLIE NAPIER."
I'm wondering if anybody know the typeface?

It's an old poster. Victorian era.

[image]

Comment: Such old fonts might be hard or even impossible to find. On archive.org there are hundreds of old *type specimen books* like [this one](https://archive.org/details/americanspecimen00amer/page/640) from 1912. Maybe you can find the font by browsing through thousands of pages ... The problem is that if you find the font it's not given that it has been digitized and even if it has it doesn't necessarily have the same name.

Comment: Thanks Wolff. That's a big help. I have to recreate things like this quite often and as you said it is hard as many fonts aren't digitized. Fortunately there are usually similar fonts. It has made me appreciate the subtle differences from font to font.

Comment: The headlines are "Victorian Woodblock type" (alternate "woodcut") the rest is unclear. I am dubious that the poster depicted is actually antique however. A "victorian broadside" has its own a particular style that this is lacking.

Comment: Yeah, this is late nineteenth, emphasis on late, stylistically. I wouldn't be astounded if you told me this was from the 1910s or 1920s. The body text is intended to be quirky-old-timey but you didn't see that in type until the end of the nineteenth century. FF Oneleigh is a really fantastic modern family that shoots for the same mood as the text font.

Comment: At first glance, the fonts that come to mind are: omni, onyx, optima all of which have the thick and thin strokes (though some might swell at the endings). They have the look of roman type faces but without the serifs.

Answer (score 1):

Garamond Bold Condensed and Britannic Bold Regular come close with some adjusting

[image]

(Excuse the misspelling)

Answer (score 1):

Contact Sovereign Hill in Ballarat, Victoria, Australia. It’s a working village museum of the victorian goldfields and the printer there still uses original equipment. I’m pretty sure this is one of their reproductions.
enquiries@sovereignhill.com.au

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE!

Answer (score -1):

What you're looking for is a "stressed" sans-serif, one with obvious contrast. At first glance I thought this was going to be the very common Old Gothic Bold Italic. It's actually slightly darker than this, but it's been digitized for free as [Racing Sans](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Racing+Sans+One). [Domaine Sans](https://klim.co.nz/collections/domaine-sans/) by Klim is a great modern font with this look if you want something more flexible. Simply slanting Britannic Bold is most of the way there, though. [image: Old Gothic Bold Italic]